# Do the Hunter ranger's Horde Breaker and Volley features interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, ranged-attack

The [Hunter ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Hunter) gets the [Hunter's Prey](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Hunter%E2%80%99sPrey-338) feature at 3rd level, one of the options for which is:

> ***Horde Breaker.*** Once on each of your turns when you make a weapon
>   attack, you can make another attack with the same weapon against a
>   different creature that is within 5 feet of the original target and
>   within range of your weapon.

One of the options for their 11th-level [Multiattack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Multiattack-340) feature is Volley:

> ***Volley.*** You can use your action to make a ranged attack against any
>   number of creatures within 10 feet of a point you can see within
>   your weapon’s range. You must have ammunition for each target, as
>   normal, and you make a separate attack roll for each target.

Now let's say that a Ranger with a bow uses Volley on a group of three creatures: C1, C2, and C3.

Can he use also Horde Breaker on one creature belonging to this group, e.g. C1, if C2 is considered the original target?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Yes

There is nothing that prohibits this interaction. The **ranged attacks** made from *Volley* count as **weapon attacks**, so any of them can be used as the "trigger" for *Horde Breaker*.

Note however that *Horde Breaker* allows you to do this only once on each of your turns, so you can't trigger it on each of the *Volley* attacks, but only on one.

In your example, you can attack each of C1, C2, and C3 once from *Volley*, and another one of them a second time, as long as the target of the *Horde Breaker* attack is within 5 feet of any of the original targets (so if C3 is further away than 5 ft from both C1 and C2, C3 will not be eligible for the *Horde Breaker* extra attack).

Comment: Additionally, instead of shooting one target twice, if there's a target just outside the 10 foot radius *Volley* grants, you may be able to use *Horde Breaker* to plink the guy that didn't quite fit in the area.